# Can type of sub class be inferred from superclass

Tags: rdf, rdfs

If we have:

```
:superclass rdf:type :classofclass
:subclass rdfs:subClassOf :superclass
:object rdf:type :subclass
```

We may certainly infer:

```
:superclass rdf:type rdfs:Class
:subclass rdf:type rdfs:Class
:object rdf:type :superclass
```

But may we also infer:

```
:subclass rdf:type :classofclass
```

Comment: not in standard RDF(S) entailment. The inference rule is `(x rdf:type A), (A rdfs:subClassOf B) -> (x rdf:type B)` , so a path from `rdf:type` over `rdfs:subClassOf`. But this is clearly not what you hope `(A rdfs:subClassOf B), (B rdf:type C) -> (A rdf:type C)`, an inference path from `rdfs:subClassOf` over `rdf:type` - add this custom rule to your custom rule engine, done. Or use a SPARQL Construct (or Update) query

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser. I'm wasn't really hoping anything, just wanted to clarify whether it _should_ work or not. I think I prefer your last suggestion (update query) rather than making a custom rule - I think it makes it more explicit what is intended.

Comment: If you want to make your comment into an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: @Cartmo for some obscure reason UninformedUser refuses to post answers here on StackOverflow, instead doing everything in comments. I suggest you take their comment and use it to post (and accept) an answer yourself.